# OraclePropertyGraphDataLoader loadData from HDFS

Tags: oracle, bigdata, graph-theory, cloudera, oracle-spatial

I'm using Spark+Hive to build graphs and relations and export flat OPV/OPE files to HDFS, one OPV/OPE CSV per reducer.
All our graph database is ready to be loaded on OPG/PGX for analytics an that worked like a charm.

Now, we want to load those vertices/edges on Oracle Property Graph.

I'v dumped the filenames from hdfs this way:

```
$ hadoop fs -find '/user/felipeferreira/dadossinapse/ops/*.opv/*.csv' | xargs -I{}  echo 'hdfs://'{} > opvs.lst
$ hadoop fs -find '/user/felipeferreira/dadossinapse/ops/*.ope/*.csv' | xargs -I{}  echo 'hdfs://'{} > opes.lst
```

And I'm experimenting on groovy shell with some issues and doubts:

```
opvs = new File('opvs.lst') as String[]
opes = new File('opes.lst') as String[]

opgdl.loadData(opg, opvs, opes, 72)
```

That doesn't work out of the box, I receive errors like

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: loadData: part-00000-f97f1abf-5f69-479a-baee-ce0a7bcaa86c-c000.csv flat file does not exist
```

I'll manage that with a InputStream approach available in the loadData interface, hope that solves this problem, but I have some questions/sugestions:

- Does loadData support vfs so I may load 'hdfs://...' files directly?
- Wouldn't be nice to have glob syntax in the filenames so we may do something like:

`opgdl.loadData(opg, 'hdfs:///user/felipeferreira/opvs/**/*.csv' ...`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What a great question! It will undoubtedly increase our knowledge concerning Oracle Spatial and Graphs.

Comment: I also would like to know more about this matter, as it can be very inconvenient to load the files using workarounds.

Comment: I'm using a workaround that's suitable for now, using the hdfs nfs gateway.
If there is a more suitable and distributable way (since nfs gateway wont use quorum), we would like to know! :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use an alternate API from `OraclePropertyGraphDataLoader` where you can specifiy the `InputStream` objects for the opv/ope files used for loading. This way, you can use `FsDataInputStream` objects to read the files from your HDFS environment.

A small sample is the following:

```
// ====== Init HDFS File System Object
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
// Set FileSystem URI
conf.set("fs.defaultFS", hdfsuri);
conf.set("fs.hdfs.impl", org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());
conf.set("fs.file.impl", org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.class.getName());
// Set HADOOP user
System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME", "hdfs");
System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "/");

//Get the filesystem - HDFS
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(hdfsuri), conf);`

// Read files into InputStreams using HDFS FsDataInputStream Java APIs
**Path pathOPV = new Path("/path/to/file.opv");
FSDataInputStream inOPV = fileSystem.open(pathOPV);
Path pathOPV = new Path("/path/to/file.ope");
FSDataInputStream inOPE = fileSystem.open(pathOPE);**

cfg = GraphConfigBuilder.forPropertyGraphHbase().setName("sinapse").setZkQuorum("bda1node05,bda1node06").build()

opg = OraclePropertyGraph.getInstance(cfg)
opgdl = OraclePropertyGraphDataLoader.getInstance();
opgdl.loadData(opg, **inOPV, inOPE**, 100);
```

Let us know if this one works for you.

Comment: Thank you, Gabriela! Web are still in SFO for the Analytics data Summit, and i’l have vacation untol next week. The first day i ter Back i’l try it and tive you Feedback!

Comment: Once again, for the sake of tracking: we actualy didn't needed to write opv/ope files to hbase. @korbi just advised me that I can load PGX directly from flatfiles. I apologise for not being carefull enough in manual reading. Anyway, since you spent your time to answer me I'll test this approach for future reference. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of tracking, here is the solution we'v adopted:

Mounted the hdfs through the NFS gateway on a folder below the groovy shell.

Exported the filenames to the OPV/OPE list-of-files:

```
$ find ../hadoop/user/felipeferreira/dadossinapse/ -iname "*.csv" | grep ".ope" > opes.lst
$ find ../hadoop/user/felipeferreira/dadossinapse/ -iname "*.csv" | grep ".opv" > opvs.lst
```

Then it was as simple as this to load the data on the opg/hbase:

```
cfg = GraphConfigBuilder.forPropertyGraphHbase().setName("sinapse").setZkQuorum("bda1node05,bda1node06").build()

opg = OraclePropertyGraph.getInstance(cfg)
opgdl = OraclePropertyGraphDataLoader.getInstance()

opvs = new File("opvs.lst") as String[]
opes = new File("opes.lst") as String[]

opgdl.loadData(opg, opvs, opes, 100)
```

This seems to get bottlenecked by the nfs gateway, but we will evaluate this next week.

Graph data loading is running just fine so far.
If anyone would suggest a better approach, please let me know!